# Diskless Computer with NFS - Shutdown Needed?

Tags: linux, shutdown, nfs

I have a computer (a Raspberry Pi, but I believe this is irrelevant for the question) running Linux. That computer runs without a disk, meaning it boots using PXE and gets a root partition hosted on an NFS server. That root partition is mounted in synchronous mode, and in normal operation nothing gets written to any system files (let's say just in user home directories).

Now I would like to remotely turn this computer on and off. It is powered via PoE, so I could just tell the switch to turn power on the respective port off (and obviously, without power, the pi would be off).

If the pi was using an SD card, I would be very hesitant about doing that, and find a way to tell it in advance to properly shut down, and then turn it off after a reasonable time.

However, in this environment, I feel it is safe to just take away the power and don't bother about shutting down. As I understand it, the worst that can happen that a file that's currently being written doesn't get written. Am I right about that? Or is there any risk when not doing a regular shutdown?

Comment: The issue would be if the Pi were writing and a *partial, corrupted,* file were to be created. However, if you're sure the Pi never writes to any location, and all work is kept in RAM, then power-off should not cause problems (assuming a clean shut-off and turn-on, without surges or slowly-changing voltages).

Comment: Well, some logfiles are written (appended to). But if they're incomplete that won't really matter. Nothing that's actually read and parsed in any way. And in the cases where I'm logging onto the machine and actually do something that would be bad if interrupted I'd include a safeguard preventing it from being turned off remotely. About clean shut-off, I really hope the switch (Cisco) can do that, although I have no idea how to test it.

Comment: Incomplete is not the same as *corrupted*. See https://support.intego.com/hc/en-us/articles/207114508-What-is-a-Corrupted-File- . Also consider that the *file system* can become corrupted.

Comment: How can the file system become corrupted if it's NFS in synchronous mode if - as it would be - a client just disconnects during a write? If the file system was a disk or SD card I obviously agree, but the point of my questions is that it is not, it's NFS!

Comment: To add to my thoughts: The client sends a write to the server, since it's synchronous this is flushed immediately, then the client loses power and cannot send other writes? Might the file that was written last be garbage afterwards? Sure, but I wouldn't care about that. Can the file system on the server be corrupted? I honestly don't see how, but that is exactly what I'm asking.